# Proof for hypercube question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

On our last discrete math test I totally missed this, but I think i'm starting to understand it. I just don't understand how to prove the following:

> Prove that the number of links in an n-dimension hypercube is n×2^(n-1) for all n≥ 1

So, It look like the "2*n" is representing the 2 nodes and the dimensions start from zero and go up. But I can barely prove this in words. Much less mathematically. How else can I "prove" this besides just explaining what numbers represent. And at which point does it become a "proof"?

Comment: [You already asked this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763458/n-dimension-hypercube-question-making-sense-of-the-question#comment1586887_763458) You know you can edit questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We proceed by induction on $n \in \mathbb N$.

**Base Case:** This holds for $n = 1$, since a $1$-dimensional hypercube consists of exactly $1 \cdot 2^{1-1} = 1$ link.

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Assume that the claim holds true for all $n' \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

It remains to prove that the claim holds true for $n' = n$. Indeed, recall that an $n$-dimensional hypercube is formed by taking two copies of an $(n-1)$-dimensional hypercube and linking together all $2^{n-1}$ pairs of corresponding nodes (using $2^{n-1}$ links). Now by the induction hypothesis, each $(n-1)$-dimensional hypercube contains $(n-1)\cdot 2^{n-2}$ links. Hence, the total number of links in an $n$-dimensional hypercube is:
$$
2 \cdot [(n-1)\cdot 2^{n-2}] + 2^{n-1}
= (n-1)\cdot 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1}
= n \cdot 2^{n-1}
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

In 1-dimensional space the cube consists of two points and a line segment joining them, so the answer is 1 which is correct. Now the n-dimensional cube consists of two n-1 dimensional cubes with the corresponding vertices joined, so try induction, it shouldn't be that hard.